# Can QGIS use forthcoming CA - QL1 Lidar for the Carr...Fire

Tags: qgis, lidar, capability

I don't use QGIS, yet.  It looks like a huge investment in time and energy to learn how to use it.  Before making that investment, I would like to know if it will meet my needs?

I want to browse the terrain and intensity data from the forthcoming USGS dataset: "CA - QL1 Lidar for the Carr, Hirz, and Delta Fire Impacted Watersheds".

Would you recommend using QGIS for this?

What basic workflow would you recommend.

Any other recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: Try taking a look at plas.io, a web based LiDAR visualization tool. https://plas.io/

Comment: Spent some time on it this evening.  Once the data is out, I'll look more closely.  Thanks